# Python String length to find character

Tags: python, string, hadoop, mapper

I am trying to use python to read input from a text file using mapper/reduce and to be outputted into many clusters using AWS EMR Hadoop(mapper). I want to output words based on the number of characters they have.
Basically in the 4 lines of the if statements below, I want to output 4 kinds of words.

1.Extra long word contains 10+ characters.

2.Long word contains 7, 8 or 9 characters.

3.Medium word contains 4, 5 or 6 characters.

4 Short word contains 3, 2 or 1 characters.

This code does not seem to be working right, though, could anyone assist me with this? 'lword' is the word, if that helps. Thanks!

```
   if pattern.match(lword) and (len(lword) <= 10:
        print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", 1)

    if pattern.match(lword) and (len(lword) >= 7 || len(lword)<=9 :
        print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", 1)

    if pattern.match(lword) and (len(lword) >= 4 || len(lword)<=6 :
        print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", 1)

     if pattern.match(lword) and (len(lword) >= 1 || len(lword)<=3 :
        print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", 1)
```

Comment: Not working in what way?

Comment: You have four times the byte for byte exact same action. This does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `and` instead of '| |' in the last three word length tests. A more readable test is, for example, `len(lword) in [7. 8. 9]`

Also the first word length test should be `>= 10` not `<= 10`.

So, assuming the `print` statements are placeholders for different actions depending on the size of `lword`:

```
if pattern.match(lword):
   if len(lword) >= 10:
       print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", 1)
   elif len(lword) in [7, 8, 9] :
       print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", 1)
   elif len(lword) in [4, 5, 6] :
       print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", 1)
   else: # lword is between one and three characters long
       print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", 1)
```

Comment: xrange is recommended over enumerating all the digits in a range

Comment: My point was in regards to readability, and in this case spelling the numbers out in a list is slightly more readable imo

Comment: Thanks craig, your explanation makes sense. I'm new to Python, I will read up more on its basic syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Craig Burgler has already pointed out that your code is using invalid `||` syntax, and shown how to avoid testing `pattern.match(lword)` more times than you need to.

Another improvement you can make is to take advantage of the fact that comparisons in Python can be chained, so that, for example

```
x = 5
if 4 <= x <= 6:
    # True
```

Also, since you're going to be testing `len(lword)` more than once, it makes sense to store it in a variable rather than calculate it over and over again:

```
word_length = len(lword)
```

Finally, since it looks like you're doing something similar with `lword` whatever its length, you carry out that action after you've done your tests. Your final code might look something like this:

```
if pattern.match(lword):
    word_length = len(lword)
    if 1 <= word_length <= 3:
        category = 1
    elif 4 <= word_length <= 6:
        category = 2
    elif 7 <= word_length <= 9:
        category = 3
    elif word_length >= 10:
        category = 4
    else:
        category = 0  # lword is empty
    print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", category)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
if (len(lword)) >= 10:
        print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", 1)

elif (len(lword) >= 7) and (len(lword) <= 9) :
        print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", 1)

elif (len(lword) >= 4) and (len(lword) <= 6) :
        print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", 1)

elif (len(lword) >= 1) and (len(lword) <= 3) :
        print '%s%s%d' % (lword, "\t", 1)
```